# Anchor text and SEO

Tags: links, anchor, text

I'm trying to figure out in terms of anchor text what types of words are good or bad for a single web page. It doesn't matter what the page is, but I want to avoid being red-flagged by search engines.

One site https://www.removeem.com/ratios.php claims that anchor text over-optimization is bad, but I'm trying to figure out, to what point is it really bad?

Are two links with different anchor texts pointing to the same URL outside of the page bad? For example. Is this type of design bad?

```
<p>Welcome to the place where we let you <a href="http://google.ca">Search</a> for goodies</p><!-- paragraph of text goes here -->
<p>If you need more help, see <a href="http://google.ca">google</a></p>
```

and what about links with the same name? for example:

```
<p>Try some <a href="http://fudge.ca">fudge</a></p>
<p>Or check out this brand of <a href="http://secondfudge.ca">fudge</a></p>
```

In the code, assume the URLs are existing.

In terms of SEO and user satisfaction, what would you suggest I should keep in mind when creating my links without running into one of the million penalties google and/or bing may impose for bad link creation?

Comment: May this helps you:https://moz.com/learn/seo/anchor-text

Answer (score 2):

You have to stop listening to all these so call SEO experts with something to sell!! This is just plain Bull Squirt! Stop buying what these SEO parroting idiots are selling. It is a fools errand to chase all this stuff. Just make a site that is honest and people enjoy. That is all you need to do.

Yes. There are [****** - lousy] links. And yes. There are people who make crappy links.

But let's not over think this!

Unless your link profile is loaded with really really spammy links, and that is almost impossible unless you are a spammer, then "no" there is no invisible line you cross, and you do not have to worry. The link examples you provided will pass muster just fine. Google is not Mother Superior ready to bludgeon you to death with a ruler in some Monty Python movie for links someone else makes. Sure some links are not optimal. Some down-right [**** - are lousy]. But this is where you take control.

You need to create your own back links that are natural. The best links possible are within content. The examples you provided seem a bit contrived. Google wants natural writing and natural links. Just do what you do. You do not have to worry about going over the edge if you are natural. Sometimes it is best to link a sentence or a large enough portion of a sentence that will reflect where a user would be going to. Make conversational links. If it helps, use the same language you would in a header tag. That is what I do. But do not over think it. It really is not that complicated.

Google gets that some links [**** - are lousy] and some don't. Just make good links and do not worry if Google is going to slap your wrist with a ruler if your grammar is not exactly correct. That just does not happen! But the people with something to sell you want you to think it does. They are our modern snake oil salesmen.

Now here is a secret I will share with you and you only. Do not let anyone know what I am about to tell you. If it gets around, who know what will happen?

There is no such thing as a bad link. True! Just links from bad sites. Some links can be improved of course, but it is the value of the linking page that is the key. Not so much the link itself. Again, some links can be improved. But keep in mind that I can have the most well optimized gold plated blessed by the freaking Pope himself link and if the linking page is no good, then what have I done?? Nothing. Links go bad when the site goes bad. Not when the verbiage is graded by Mother Superior.

Comment: ok just making sure because my income went down, but I will now check the server to see if I can give it a further boost.

Comment: @Mike As far as links go, you do want to use important terms but you want to be conversational except of course for buttons. Create as many back links as you can within content in normal conversational ways. You do want to vary the links somewhat of course. Just know that Google is only making semantic links to understand language and intent. They do not worry about the details as much as where the link comes from. Even poorly made links on high value sites can really boost your presence. You have it in you to make a great site! I know this. Just make it the best you can for a human audience.

Comment: @Mike Also, remember what I said about money terms. You have to use the terms to gain the right audience of course, but within your content, put in some red meat that bidders will like. I raised my RPM by $3.00 in the past month with only 1/4 of my normal traffic doing this. You can talk about drinks, meals, rate the party or place, something of value for the advertisers. That may help. But do it in such away as to retain your audience and possibly gain some new ones. I like what you are doing. Just add some new value to your site that will earn you some coin and new traffic.

Comment: I understand but the problem is that I live 60km away from the action and I don't get much input from people to write about and the audience is interested in pictures 99.9% of the time and don't care about reading.

Comment: Gotcha! Maybe a forum that people who were there can BS in? Or a rating system that they can vote up or down? Perhaps you can sell advertising directly to pubs or product manufacturers? There has to be something clever that will work for you. It will come to you. It might take time, then bingo! A jem of an idea. A spark.

Comment: @Mike In case you cannot tell, you have me in your corner mate! Promise.

Comment: I'm gonna have to figure something out. Now it got worse because I used to have a feature where people can directly share pictures and info with facebook, but since facebook updated things and expects me to agree to making the pictures royalty free, I'm not using them anymore

Comment: @Mike Royalty free just means that they do not have to pay for it. That would be expected for any website including yours. As long as they are not talking about copyright which they cannot do as a 3rd party entity without the consent of the owner. What about Pinterest?? Or StumbeUpon?? Would these be something of value?? I tend to like Twitter even though I do not use it- I have nothing to say really. But perhaps you can tweet some of the photos with location or something?